# ¿Cómo saber la llave que mas tiene un valor en una lista de diccionarios?

Tags: python

Hola a toda la comunidad, hoy traigo un problema en el cual debo crear una función que recibe como parámetro una lista de diccionarios con información de atletas con diversas llaves y regresar el país que acumule más medallas, el parámetro de entrada luce así:

```
    [{'nombre': 'milie andol','genero': 'f','edad': 28,'pais': 'france','anio': 2016,'evento': 
    "judowomen's heavyweight",'medalla': 'gold'}]
```

Cuando un atleta no ha ganado una medalla luce así: *´medalla':na*

Si por ejemplo a la función le entra una lista más larga, debe analizar los atletas que tienen medallas de 'oro', 'plata' o 'bronce', así el país que tenga más atletas con alguna de estas medallas, será el retorno de la función que será un diccionario que tenga como llave el nombre del país y como valor el número de medallas así:

```
    diccionario_resultado={pais:num_medallas}
```

El código que tengo luce así:

```
    def pais_con_mas_medallas(todos_los_atletas:list)->dict:
        lista_paises=[]
        lista_paises_ordenada=[]
        diccionario_final={}
        contador_medallas=0
        pais_con_mas_medallas=""
        for cada_diccionario in todos_los_atletas:
            pais=cada_diccionario["pais"]
            lista_paises.append(pais)
            lista_paises_ordenada=sorted(set(lista_paises))
            for cada_pais in lista_paises_ordenada:
                if cada_diccionario["pais"]==cada_pais:
                    if cada_diccionario["medalla"]!="na":
                        contador_medallas+=1
                        pais_con_mas_medallas=cada_diccionario["pais"]
                        diccionario_final={"pais":pais_con_mas_atletas,"medallas":contador_medallas}
        return diccionario_final
```

El problema con este código es que cuenta simplemente todas las medallas que están en la lista y el retorno es el último país en la lista con todas las medallas.

Nota: si varios países tienen la misma cantidad de medallas, en el diccionario aparecerán estos países.

Answer (score 1):

Existen varias aproximaciones posibles, pero una muy simple es:

- Creas un diccionario en el que la clave es el país y el valor el recuento de medallas.
- Iteras sobre la lista de atletas y por cada uno con una medalla le sumas uno al contador de su país en el diccionario anterior.
- Terminada la iteración, buscas la clave con el valor más alto y generas otro diccionario con las parejas de éste cuyo valor sea se máximo

---

```
def pais_con_mas_medallas(todos_los_atletas: list) -> dict:
    paises = {}
    for atleta in todos_los_atletas:
        if atleta["medalla"] != "na":
            pais = atleta["pais"]
            if pais in paises:
                paises[pais] += 1
            else:
                paises[pais] = 1

    max_medallas = 0    
    for _, medallas in paises.items():
        if medallas > max_medallas:
            max_medallas = medallas

    return {pais: medallas for pais, medallas in paises.items() if medallas == max_medallas}
```

Puedes también usar `collections.Counter` para que haga parte del trabajo anterior, la idea es realmente la misma, solo que le delegas el trabajo de contar y de obtener el máximo:

```
import collections

def pais_con_mas_medallas(todos_los_atletas: list) -> dict:
    paises = collections.Counter(
        atleta["pais"] for atleta in todos_los_atletas if atleta["medalla"] != "na")
    max_medallas = paises.most_common(1)[0][1]
    return {pais: medallas for pais, medallas in paises.items() if medallas == max_medallas}
```

Comment: Okey entiendo, de hecho no conocía la función collections.conter pero parece ser de mucha ayuda. El método .items() no lo conozco muy bien y no termino de entender su función dentro del retorno por lo que me gustaría saber que papel cumple. Probé el primer código y funciona a la perfección, solo me queda esa duda, gracias.

Comment: El método `dict.items` genera una vista del diccionario con las claves y sus valores en parejas, simplemente retorna un iterable con las parejas clave valor en forma de tupla, por ejemplo, para el diccionario `{"france": 2, "germany": 3}` genera algo como `(("france", 2), "germany", 3))`. Por lo tanto al hacer `for pais, medallas in paises.items()` en cada iteración la variable `pais` se asigna a una clave y la variable `medalla` a su valor y de ésta forma vamos iterando sobre el diccionario.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya comprendo lo que hace el método items, gracias por tu ayuda en la resolución de mi problema

Answer (score 1):

Una posibilidad es usar una comprensión de listas para crear una lista con los nombres de todos los países que tienen alguna medalla. Después usas `collections.Counter()` sobre esa lista, y eso te da un diccionario en el que las claves serán los países y los valores el número de medallas que tiene cada uno.

La clase `Counter()` te permite obtener también el más frecuente (`.most_common(1)`), que es el que mayor número de medallas tiene. Por si acaso hubiera empate en el top, puedes quedarte con el número de medallas de ese país, y luego iterar sobre el resultado de `Counter()` para crear otro diccionario con todos aquellos que tengan ese número.

Es decir:

```
from collections import Counter

def pais_con_mas_medallas(todos_los_atletas:list)->dict:
  c = Counter(d["pais"] for d in todos_los_atletas if d["medalla"]!="na")
  record = c.most_common(1)[0][1]
  return {pais: contador for pais, contador in c.items() if contador==record}
```